# Error log reports when I log to admin

Tags: magento-1.9, error, login, log

When I am trying to log in to the website admin panel I am receiving this error `record number: 1186363524883`.

[image]

Please provide some solution.

Comment: Please go to `var/reports` and post the content of the file with this number.

Answer (score 1):

Either you would need to enable developer mode from /index.php like this

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set(’display_errors’, 1);
}


TO

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    ini_set(’display_errors’, 1);
}
```

or as suggested above go to var/report/{Quoted File on the screen}

Answer (score 0):

Enable exception printing to see what the problem is.

Rename file `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` that is located in `<root_directory>/errors/`

You can also configure Magento to send the exception to an email address defined in that file.

Comment: Don't do this on a production server, of course, as it is a security risk